# Java Stream map to multiple attribute

Tags: java, json, option-type

I'm using `Optional<ObjectNode>` and extracting various attributes out of it using streams.

```
class MyCompany {
    private Age age;
    private Name name;

    // getters and setters

}

        myJSON
                .map(jsonObj -> getAge(jsonObj, "age"))
                .map(age -> new Age(age))
                .ifPresent(myCompany::setAge);


        myJSON
                .map(jsonObj -> getName(jsonObj, "name"))
                .map(name -> new Name(name))
                .ifPresent(myCompany::setName);

public Integer getAge(ObjectNode jsonObj, String toGet) {
    Integer value = null;

    if (jsonObj(toGet)) {

        value = jsonObj(toGet).intValue();

    }

    return value;
}
```

Now I want to change the `MyCompany` to include a new `Person` class instead and `Person` shall include the name and age attributes. How can I use the Java stream in a single statement to formulate `Person` from the name and age and then set it in `MyCompany`

```
class Person {
    private Age age;
    private Name name;
    // getters and setters


    public void Person(Age age, Name name) {
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;

    }
}

class MyCompany {
    private Person person;
    //getters and setters for Person
}
```

Comment: What is `myJSON` in your fragment code?

Comment: Optional<ObjectNode> , ObjectNode being jackson

Comment: What is the definition of `getAge(jsonObj, "age")`? Replace it to make use of an `ObjectMapper` (since you are using Jackson already). Then map to your concrete object directly. On a different note, (1) you haven't used java-streams in tthe code yet, it's `Optional` that is responsible for the `map `and `ifPresent` APIs. (2) `getAge(jsonObj, "name")` seems like a typo or misnomer.

Comment: I added the method for `getAge` I've similar for `getName`

Comment: can you show the json input

Answer (score 0):

There is no more info about `Optional<ObjectNode>` in your fragment code, have a try with below code.

```
@Test
public void test2() {

    //MyCompany JSON String
    String myCompany = "{\"age\":20,\"name\":\"Tom\"}";
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.parseObject(myCompany);

    //convert to Company with Person
    Optional<Company> tom = Stream.of(jsonObject).map(m -> new Person(m.getInteger("age"), m.getString("name")))
            .map(p -> new Company(p)).findFirst();
    if (tom.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println(tom.get());
        //output in console
        //Tests.Company(person=Tests.Person(age=20, name=Tom))
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Company {
    private Person person;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
static class MyCompany {
    private int age;
    private String name;
}
```